# Is this equivalent to NP?

Tags: algorithms

If we had a question **Q(n)** for which there is an alogorithm **A(n)** that can solve a problem in polynomial time **P(n)**  and can be checked in logarithmic time **Log(n)**.

Then we could define a new set of questions $$Q'(n)=Q(2^n)$$ which then has an algorithm that can solve it in non-polynomial time but can be checked in polynomial time.

So $Q(n)$ is in **P** and $Q'(n)$ is in **NP**. If this was the case then $P\neq NP$.

Therefor is it correct to say a proof of $P\neq NP$ would be solved if there was a set of questions which could be solved in polynomial time but checked in logarithmic time?

Answer (score 2):

Even throwing on the implicit sharpness conditions (you presumablywant $Q$ to be solvable in polynomial time *but not* in logarithmic time), this isn't enough.

The issue is that $Q'$ only "samples" a small fraction of $Q$: maybe, even though general inputs to $Q$ take polynomially-long to solve, whenever I input a power of $2$ the answer happens to be very easy to figure out! (E.g. maybe the answer to $Q(n)$ is always "no" if $n$ is a power of $2$ - then $Q'$ is really quite simple, regardless of how complicated $Q$ itself is.)

To make this work, you would need to define $Q'$ so that it grabs "appropriately complicated" $Q$-instances. Moreover, the way we pick these $Q$-instances would itself have to be simple, or we wouldn't be able to conclude $Q'\in\mathsf{NP}$. It's not at all clear how to do any of that.